# Sailsjs angular-toastr error

Tags: angularjs, sails.js

I've just followed the instructions in the sailsjs tutorial and I got this error on the browser:

> [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: directives/toast/toast.html

I've checked the folder named directives but there are no such folder;
Do I need to install something like angular-toastr on npm?
I have already angular-toaster.js on my dependencies (Just follow the instruction on the tutorial of sailsjs).

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Yes, you need to install `angular-toastr` for your frontend build pipeline. You might be using `npm` or `bower` or `webpack` etc. for this. Please share link of tutorial.

Comment: I've just read the instruction for the angular-toastr here https://github.com/Foxandxss/angular-toastr, I tried downloading the latest release and added the file angular-toastr.tpls.js on my dependencies then it work. I think the tpls means templates. I'm now wondering why on the tutorial there is no file like that. Thanks though.

Comment: How are you managing Angular build or How is `angular.js` and other front-end files are available to your HTML?

Comment: It uses the pipline. I just put the js files on the assets/js/dependencies then the pipline will just load those files on its identifier(<!--SCRIPTS--><!--SCRIPTS END-->) on the html file. Am I missing something? Should I use bower?

Comment: I don't have understanding of your setup. So, I'm making guesses here. Are you using `angular-toastr.js` or `angular-toastr.tpls.js`. Use `.tpls` one.

Comment: I've just cloned the ch6-end sailsjs tutorial. It includes the angular-toastr.js instead of angular-toastr.tpls.js. Also the tutorial does'nt say I will use bower (or something like that) on the chapter where I'am which is ch7.

Comment: Please include link of tutorial. and try with `angular-toastr.tpls.js`

Comment: I use the book of the creator, I already include that file and it work. Thanks for the help, means a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Use `angular-toastr.tpls.js` instead. It contains templates